# How to fix this Big eyebrow that keeps appearing after trying to get eyebrow

Tags: texturing, hair

[image: model with pink eyebrows]

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong and properly show me as well, because it would be a shame for me to give up on something I love.the bottom is what i'm trying to get when i render it,but when i render it comes weird looking as the top.please help

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about why the eyebrow is pink or some other question about the size of the particles maybe?

Comment: I'm not worrying about the pink eyebrow, but your saying its the particles that has it that big?

Comment: Well your question is quite unclear. (I still dont know what you are trying to change) Is it just the size? I was guessing that you are using particles. How are you making the eye brows?

Comment: @Ashton, please be more specific about what's going wrong, what you expect to see, and how you've tried to fix it. Is this a texture? Is this a particle system? Is the eyebrow bigger than you want? Are you asking why it's pink? Help us help you ;-)

Comment: ok to be honest, I was following the video tutorial on how to create eyebrows,but everytime i do it, it becomes a Big eyebrows or something. I have all the hair correct for the eyebrow in particle edit correct and yet that keep happening

Comment: sorry bro, but i'm still getting use blender names and all but i under the basics and how to get what i need with it, but i'm still a noob to it. but yes this a particle,no texture and if i add texture only the color shows.

Comment: so my question is how do i get to look normal like a eyebrow again and what cause this to happen like this?

Comment: maybe its the "skinhead.001" that is hidden in the 3D view but is still allowed to render in the final?

Comment: Upload your .blend using http://blender.stackexchange.com/ and perhaps we can get a better grasp on what's happening.